# Writing specs using kitchen for chef scripts - writing the kitchen.yml file

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have few recipes and I want to test them using kitchen.

I am new to kitchen and I was going through their docs which is really good.

```
---
driver:
  name: ssh

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver:
      hostname: 123.456.789.10
      username: root
      password: blahblah

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[redis::default]     
    attributes:
```

I have a lot of cookbooks ,

```
Lvl1 Main Folder
Lvl2|--> kitchen init
    |-->cookbook 
Lvl3   |--> A
          |--> recipes 
       |--> B
          |--> recipes
```

So basically I have way too many recipes inside a main cookbook folder. 
Is it possible to run kitchen test on level 1 itself by mentioning it under `run_list` somehow?
Hope I am clear.

I basically want to test it on a higher level since by cookbooks are all interdependent.

Comment: I hope you get my question. :-)

Comment: hey I have one question for you, regarding to this. I have a very similar .kitchen.yml file, that is using SSH as a driver. So my question is, have you faced an error when you try to converge saying something like "Message: Could not load the 'ssh' driver from the load path."

Comment: You need to install the 'ssh' driver provided. I hope you `gem install kitchen-ssh` . It should work now. Let me know :)

Comment: hey! thank you so much for your answer! unfortunately I did that but didn't worked... so I took another solution... remove the project and clone the repo from scratch, ran bundle install again, berks install and so on... fortunately this time worked, so I assume that was more related with an environment issue rather than a kitchen problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make a `Berksfile` that looks like:

```
cookbook 'A', path: 'A'
cookbook 'B', path: 'B'
```

In the base folder next to your `.kitchen.yml`. Then you can make a suite like:

```
- name: A
  run_list:
  - recipe[A]
```

or:

```
- name: both
  run_list:
  - recipe[A]
  - recipe[B]
```